# javascript objects cant see each other? :: google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, object, google-chrome-extension

i have two files

one called stats.js

one called storage.html

in stats.js in contains

```
var stats = {
  myFunc : function() {
    //do something
  }
}
```

in storage.html I have

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="stats.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   stats.myFunc(); 
});
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

But I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'myFunc' of undefined

---

**Update**
Ok so that was a really simplified example.

The basics of it are,

This is a google chrome extension, So you will see some code specific to that.

Here is the literal pages concerned:

**Popup.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Extension</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/popup.js"></script>
        <script src="js/statsapi.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/popup.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(background.storage.get('firstRun') == null)
        background.initialize();

    if(background.storage.get('metaExpire') >= Date.parse(Date()))
        background.updateMeta();

    $('#content').append(read_object(stats.getMetaData()));
});

function read_object(object){
    var $obj = $('<div />');
    for(var o in object) {
        $obj.append(o+' : ');
        if(typeof(object[o]) == 'object' && object[o] != null)
            $obj.append(read_object(object[o]));
        else
            $obj.append(object[o]+'<br />');
    }
    return $obj;
}
```

**Manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Halo Reach: Stats",
  "description": "This extension allows you to keep track of your own, and your friends Halo Reach Stats.",
  "version": "1.0.0.1",
  "permissions": [
    "http://www.bungie.net/"
  ],
  "icons": { 
      "128": "images/logo/logo128.jpg",
      "64": "images/logo/logo64.jpg",
      "32": "images/logo/logo32.jpg",
      "16": "images/logo/logo16.jpg"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Open Stats",
    "default_icon": "images/logo/logo32.jpg",
    "popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background_page": "background.html"
}
```

**statsapi.js**

```
var background  = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
var apikey      = background.storage.get('apikey');
var gamertage   = background.storage.get('gamertag');
var page        = '0';

var stats = {
    getMetaData : function() {
        var url = 'http://www.bungie.net/api/reach/reachapijson.svc/game/metadata/'+apikey;
        console.log(url);
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function(data) {
                return data;
            }
        });
    },

    meta : {
        read : function(param) {
            var meta = background.storage.get('metaData');
        }
    }
};
```

**Background.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/statsapi.js"></script>
        <script>
            var storage = {
                set : function (key, value) {
                    window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
                    window.localStorage.setItem(key, value);
                },            
                get : function (key) {
                    return window.localStorage.getItem(key);
                },            
                clear : function () {
                    window.localStorage.clear();
                }
            };

            function updateMeta() {
                var meta = stats.getMetaData();
                if(meta['status'] == 0){
                    storage.set('metaData', JSON.stringify(meta));
                    storage.set('metaExpire', Date.parse(Date())+900000);
                }
            }

            function initialize() {
                storage.set('apikey', '***');
                storage.set('gamertag', 'The Hailwood');
                updateMeta();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

When the extension is invoked it calls popup.html

and the document ready javascript is invoked.

The check for first run fails,

so it calls `initialize()` in background.html

But this is where the error occurs.

the actual error is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getMetaData' of undefined.

So why can it not see the stats class?

its not a script include problem as if the path is wrong for the statsapi.js I get

> Uncaught ReferenceError: stats is not defined.

The issue seems to be with the `var stats {}` as if under that I have a function called test() I can call that fine :/

Hmm,

is there an issue because it is an external stylesheet?

Comment: Is that *all* that's in `stats.js`? Or is it wrapped in something else?

Comment: Can you supply your `manifest.json` structure please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the error lies somewhere else - these are my examples:

```
mark@localhost:~/ccsite$ cat cat.js 
var stats = {
  myFunc : function() {
    alert('wtf');
  }
}


mark@localhost:~/ccsite$ cat hat.htm 
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="cat.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   stats.myFunc(); 
});
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Viewing hat.htm in either FF, IE6 or Chrome produces the alert, 'wtf'. As written you'd get $ is undefined, since it's not including jQuery of course, so I added that.

So, your problems likely are elsewhere. I assume this is a simplified example - what else is going on in your page?

Answer (score 1):

This is because there is some syntax error in your code. I had same problem. I opened my background.html page in fire fox with fire-bug plug-in enabled. Fire-bug console should me the error, I fixed and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I have suspicions that it's because you include `js/statsapi.js` script into both your popup and background page, so it gets confused which stats you are referring to as you have 2 of them in the popup - one included through `script` tag and another one loaded from background page after you call `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()`

Comment: nope, I need to include it separately in the background page as all calls to that are independent of the popup page.